# Keep A Constant Table Size?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I currently have a table that has a few hidden text boxes... The text boxes become visible when certain actions are performed.

The table though changes size according to when the textboxes are visible or now. Ex. When the textboxes are visible the table grows, and vice versa.

I would like to keep the table size at its max size ( size when the text boxes are visible) even when they are not.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have something inside the td tags, like a `&nbsp;`  This will cause the td to render.

Another way is to set the controls to "hidden" instead of "none".  Hidden allows the controls to still be rendered to html, just not displayed.  None will cause the controls to not be rendered at all.

I don't know if the "hidden" setting will still grab the space you want.  You might still need the non-breaking space control.